# XAML binding from 2 XAML objects -Xamarin

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, xamarin

I want to set property `IsEnabled` of button based on switch and picker using binding. Something like this:

XAML:

```
<Button Text="Start tracking"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 1, 1, 0.1"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
            x:Name="startTrackingButton"
            IsEnabled="{Binding}"
            Clicked="StartTracking_Clicked"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
```

Code behind:

```
startTrackingButton.BindingContext = (!autoTrackingSwitch.IsToggled || frequencyPicker.IsSet);
```

This solution does not work. How can I do it? Thank you.

Comment: Use multitrigger :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/Xamarin.Forms.MultiTrigger?view=xamarin-forms

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Style`:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
  <Style.Triggers>
    <MultiTrigger>
      <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <BindingCondition Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference autoTrackingSwitch}, Path=IsToggled}" Value="True"/>
        <BindingCondition Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference frequencyPicker}, Path=IsSet}" Value="True"/>
      </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
      <Setter Property="Enabled" Value="True"/>
    </MultiTrigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

You can specify it inside `Button.Resources` of your button.

Comment: Xamarin does not support `MultiDataTrigger`, it does support `MultiTrigger` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/Xamarin.Forms.MultiTrigger?view=xamarin-forms